# input focus outer glow

Tags: jquery, html, css

is it possible to simulate the outer glow that safari and other browsers add to an input field? And avoiding jquery if possible?

This article explains how to remove it:
http://www.altrugon.com/css/remove-safaris-input-focus-outer-glowquitar-el-border-azul-de-los-inputs-en-safari/

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### [Check out the DEMO](http://jsbin.com/irapo4/4)

Here `box-shadow` is used in combination with `:focus` psudo selector.

**CSS:**

```
input:focus,textarea:focus,select:focus{
  border:1px solid #fafafa;
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6px #007eff;
  -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px #007eff;
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: @user441365: You can check out CSS3Pie that claims to make box-shadow work in IE: http://css3pie.com/. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: I never really had the need for this feature until I saw this answer. +1 for the tip.

Comment: you should add `outline: none`

Comment: @roberkules: You are right, I had not checked it in Chrome :) updated now.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to simulate it exactly as it's displayed on webkit browsers you could use [CSS3 Box shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) using the [:focus pseudo class](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-focus), although note that CSS3 is not supported on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with css:

```
input:focus
{
    outline:#00FF00 solid thick;
}
```

This is the html:

```
<input />
<br/>
<br/>
<input />
```