# CSS: Double-Border, how to

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [input focus outer glow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750477/input-focus-outer-glow)

How do I do this in CSS? On focus it looks like it has a double border...

[image: Login Form]

Comment: I think this covers it pretty well: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750477/input-focus-outer-glow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750477/input-focus-outer-glow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input:focus { property to apply }
```

for a live example check out the followng fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/L5xvJ/

```
input:focus { 
border: 1px solid #0af; 
outline: none; 
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 170, 255,.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 170, 255,.5);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 170, 255,.5); }
```

notet :focus should not be confused with :active ->
[What is the difference between :focus and :active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677990/what-is-the-difference-focus-and-active)

Comment: cool, a -1 for having the same answer everyone else has...was it because i was first?

Comment: Although it wasn´t me, it´s easy to see why your original answer was downvoted: It did not answer the question at all.

Comment: well, you are right, I didn't do everything just right. But I was trying to point him in the right direction with :focus and box-shadow

Comment: Although it wasn't me, this doesn't match the style correctly either. It's close, but not very.

Comment: Right, perhaps I wasn't interpreting your question correctly. I wasn't trying to do it spot-on, but more so pointing you towards the :focus selector. It seemed you were unfamiliar with its function and I wanted to encourage you to have a look.